# Plotting in shell script using gnuplot

Tags: shell, for-loop, plot, gnuplot

I have a very long and probably a very daunting question as well. I have a trial.csv file that looks something like this:

```
ForceX  ForceY  Temp    Speed   Theta   Height
9.724   10.504  88.041   0.7      1      1100
13.938  10.841  99.918   0.7      2      1100
8.771   10.719  75.8     0.8      1      1100
12.71   11.027  85.214   0.8      2      1100
```

For every speed value there are two sets of values for ForceX, ForceY, Temp and Theta. I would like to plot ForceX against Theta for speed = 0.7 and for speed = 0.8. Now this is easy if there are just two theta values and I can use `plot "<(sed -n '2,3p' trial.csv)" using 2:1 with linespoints title ""`   for the respective speeds.

But the theta value varies from say -2 to +2 and the speed ranges from say 0.6 to 0.9. So now I have 5 sets of values for every speed. (The trial.csv is generated using a 'for' loop using speed as the outer loop and Theta as the inner loop).

How do I plot the range of ForceX with Theta for every speed value in a separate plot? I am quite new to shell scripting and I haven't found a proper solution for about a week now. I hope my problem is clear. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Regards,
Sou

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use shell scripting, you can do this much easier with gnu plot's `using` directive. For example, to plot `ForceX` vs. `Theta` for only those records where `Speed` is 0.7, use

```
plot "trial.csv" u 5:($4 == 0.7 ? $1 : 1/0) title "Speed 0.7" w lp
```

If you want to plot curves for multiple values of `Speed` try

```
plot for [speed in "0.7 0.8"] "trial.csv" u 5:($4 == speed ? $1 : 1/0) title "Speed ".speed w lp
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :D  I found a work around for it.